# How to get the referer from remote file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, referrer

I set a PHP script that output JSON like the following:

```
<?php
 // ref.php
print json_encode(array('ref' => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

The above code is all the code in that file. From another file I tried to read the output as follows:

```
<?php
// ref_index.php
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/4test/ref.php'); 
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

The above code returns NULL because the ref.php failed to get the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` value, so when I replace `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` with any fixed value, such as 'blahh blahh` it returns json object.

My question is: How could I get the referral of file_get_contents() i.e the url that it runs from to get data from my application.

Comment: Every entry beginning with `HTTP_` is from the HTTP request’s header. If you don’t send a `Referer` header field in your request to `ref.php`, there won’t be a `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

Comment: `$_SERVER` contains data of the request that invoked your script. It has absolutely NOTHING to do with the http request that php will be doing to your `ref.php` script. That'll be a completely separate/independent request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *referrer* is transferred using the `Origin` header in HTTP. You would need to set that header in your `file_get_contents()` call. To achieve this, you would need to use a customized *stream context* using [`stream_context_create()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and pass that as the third param to [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Origin: SET REFERRER URL HERE"
  )
);

echo file_get_contents(
    'http://localhost/4test/ref.php',
    false,
    stream_context_create($opts)
);
```

Comment: Oh! So, by this way I could not able to make an authentication for the remote website that with ref.php! In other words, I planed to check the referer value from a list of registered websites to allow giving them the data. Is there any workaround such as Facebook uses with their apps?!